# Functions and arguments

Tags: c++

If I have a function such as

```
int mathscalc (int a, int b = 5)
{

}
```

And I call the function mathscalc(a), how can I only do 1 argument when it requires 2? if that's possible.

Comment: The second parameter has got a default value that gets used if you don't provide a second argument for the call.

Answer (score 5):

`b` has a default value. If it is not specified, it is 5, if it is specified, it is the value, that is given.

For example:

```
mathscalc(3, 10) // b is 10 inside the function call

mathscalc(3) // b is 5 inside the function call
```

Answer (score 1):

This is well explained in C++11 Standard.

§8.3.6 Default arguments [dcl.fct.default]

> 1 If an initializer-clause is specified in a parameter-declaration this initializer-clause is used as a default argument. Default arguments will be used in calls where trailing arguments are missing.

2 [ Example: the declaration

```
void point(int = 3, int = 4);
```

declares a function that can be called with zero, one, or two arguments of type int. It can be called in any of these ways:

```
point(1,2); point(1); point();
```

The last two calls are equivalent to `point(1,4) and point(3,4)`, respectively. —end example ]

3 A default argument shall be specified only in the **parameter-declaration-clause** of a function declaration or in a template-parameter (14.1); in the latter case, the **initializer-clause** shall be an assignment-expression. A default argument shall not be specified for a parameter pack. If it is specified in a **parameter-declarationclause**, it shall not occur within a **declarator** or **abstract-declarator** of a p**arameter-declaration**.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `mathscalc` with only one argument then `b` will be set to it's default `5`.

Answer (score 0):

A value of **5** has been already assigned to the variable `b` in your **`mathscalc`** function.

So if you pass value **2** to `a` , say the  **`mathscalc`** has a multiplication operation of `c = a*b;` the result of `c` will be **10**.

If you explicitly pass `a=2` and `b=3` to your **`mathscalc`** function, the existing value assigned to `b=5` will be overwritten to `b=3`, so the result of `c` will be **6**.

Answer (score 0):

If you make call to mathscalc function with one say,

```
   mathscalc(4);
```

Compiler intern changes this function with

```
   mathscalc(4, 5);
```

But, if you make a call with two args say,

```
   mathscalc(4, 10);
```

Compiler will not replace that b with 5 instead it uses 10 in the place of b.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those function calls are possible and are known as default arguments. The default arguments should be used in the last, the inverse of that ie.,

int mathscalc (int a = 5, int b)

is not possible.

If the corresponding function call is made as,

mathscalc (5,6); 'b' will take value 6,

else if it is made as  mathscalc (5); 'b' will take the default value 5.